# saving blank image of jqplot

Tags: jqplot

I'm able to create/draw chart with jqplot. When I right-click on it and save it as PNG, it is saving a blank image.
Here is the image data:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAbkAAAEeCAYAAAAXTWt+AAACAElEQVR4nO3BMQEAAADCoPVPbQ0PoAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAJ4MtD8AAaRK8nUAAAAASUVORK5CYII=
```

Could anybody let me know is this image data is good and can I save it?

Thanks a million!

-Parameshwar

Comment: That is indeed a blank 441x286px image.  I'm not sure what you are asking here?  Can you show some code?

Comment: I have copied some simple bar chart code from jqplot site, it is drawing the bars without any problem. But when I right-click on it and save it, it saves nothing.

Comment: Could you post your code? We can help you much easier that way.

Answer (score 0):

jqPlot can convert it's chart to a image with the function *jqplotToImageStr()*
You have to run a JavaScript to convert the dynamic chart to a savable image.

See the answers here:
[JqPlot As Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12182598/jqplot-as-image)

Answer (score 0):

I render images from graphs without any problem...

```
    var imgData = $('#chart').jqplotToImageStr({});
```

Then I send to a php page the imgData var (that contains the base64 image) to let it be downloaded directly.
I you want just to show that image, you just have to add that var to the src attr of a image tag (or opening it as a popup passing the var as the href attr of the window)

```
    window.open(imgData,"_blank","scrollbars=0");
```

Anyway, if you pass that base64 code to a php page, you can download it using that code (and appropriate headers):

```
    $data = $_POST['data']; //your base64 code
    $data = substr($data,22); //remove some unuseful chars
    $img=base64_decode($data); //decode data
    $out = "../tmp/report_".date("d-m-Y_His").".png"; //set output image location 
    file_put_contents($out, $img); //create file
    echo $out; //let user direct download it
```