# How to convert the div content to an image and download in IE6+ versions?

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I have used JQPlot in my project and i want to download the plotted graph as an image. I want to support IE7+.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had once faced the same problem. Please refer the following URL, it was much helpful for me
[JqPlot As Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12182598/jqplot-as-image)
 for IE7 support Use the following library http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/source/browse/trunk/silverlight/excanvas.js?r=48 This support canvas feature in IE.