# Jqplot image download by a button click in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jqplot

I have jqplot and I want to download it once click a button as a jpg or png. I can do it using

```
$('#chartdiv').jqplotSaveImage();
```

(chartdiv is the div with plot)

It is working in chrome and firefox only. In IE it is not working.I tried in IE 11.

And I have another problem in chrome the downloaded image file name is 'download' and in firefox it is some wired name with .part extension (ex :- ka8ShgKH.part). Is there a way to put plot title as the download file name ?

thank you.

```
$("#btnSaveImg").on("click", LoadImage);

LoadImage = function(){
    $('#chartdiv').jqplotSaveImage();
}
```

**EDIT**
jqplotsaveimage function

```
$.fn.jqplotSaveImage = function() {
    var imgData = $(this).jqplotToImageStr({});
    if (imgData) {
        window.location.href = imgData.replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
    }

};
```

Comment: Miss the function jqplotSaveImage().. please load the script inside the question...

Comment: @MirkoCianfarani I added that function above. It is a function that in jquery.jqplot.js file.

Comment: Looks like you are out of luck.  IE is very specific about how and where the `data URIs` will work: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @Mark thank you for the valuable response. Can you please tell me is there a any method to download jqplot by a button click, working on main three browsers(chrome,firefox and IE) ?

Comment: I'm assuming you have access to the web-server?  You could write a simple script that you POST the base64 encoded plot to and it just sends it back as a file. You could control the file's name like that as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using jqPlot and I had issues using the above in IE and even if it worked in Chrome I could not name the downloaded image.

I found this case [force download base64 image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27327965/force-download-base64-image) and the http://danml.com/download.html . That's working both in later versions of IE and Chrome and you can save the image with your own filename. The download.js can be used for more than just images.

```
//include the downoad.js file from http://danml.com/download.html

<button id="dwnl-chart-1" onClick="$.fn.jqplotSaveImage('chart-1', 'chart_name">Download as image</button>

    $.fn.jqplotSaveImage = function(id, filename) {

        var imgData = $('#'+id+'-parent').jqplotToImageStr({});
        if (imgData) {
            download(imgData, filename+'.png', "image/png");
        }
    };
```